# Optimization of sorting of subsequent child nodes under the tree like hierarchy

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a root node which has 3 child nodes. Each of the child nodes has its own child nodes further. These child nodes are maintained as Lists. I want to sort the entire tree from top to bottom. For e.g.: First sort the 3 child nodes(according to their names) and then sort the child nodes under them. I also know the height of the tree here which is 6.
This is not a data structure tree per say but I am calling it a tree because of the kind of structure it has. I have implemented a sorting mechanism and its working fine but I am afraid this is not the most optimized way to achieve the sorting.

```
//sort the child nodes under root
GlobalProperties.Tree.ChildNodes.Sort((x,y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));

foreach (var node in GlobalProperties.Tree.ChildNodes)
{
    //sorting at second level
    node.ChildNodes.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));

    foreach (var secNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        //sorting at third level
        secNode.ChildNodes.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
        foreach (var terNode in secNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            //sorting at fourth level
            terNode.ChildNodes.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
            foreach (var fourthNode in terNode.ChildNodes)
            {
                 //sorting at fifth level
                 fourthNode.ChildNodes.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: you can use recursive function which takes a collection of nodes (childnodes) and does the sorting. it will reduce the amount of code you have and it would also be scalable for a different tree depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your nodes have a common base type.
You could supply your base type with a sort function.

```
private void Sort()
{
     this.ChildNodes.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name)); // your sort

     foreach (var node in this.ChildNodes)
    {
         node.Sort(); // this calls the Sort function for all children
    }
}
```

node.Sort() is a recursive call. It gets called for all children. And then all children will again call it for all of their children until you are at the bottom of your tree.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for an extension method in this case -

```
public static class XmlExtensions{
     public static void SortChildren(tihs XmlNode node){
          node.ChildNodes.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
          node.ChildNodes.ForEach(x => x.SortChildren());
     }
}
```

Then use it as this -

```
GlobalProperties.Tree.SortChildren();
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally don't like to get distracted by optimizing code unless performance is noticeably slow, as long as your code is clean, readable and correct, I wouldn't worry about it. Using a recursive function as indicated in the previous answer would make it easier to read, so I would definitely consider that.